# Difference between Kartavya and Dharma?

Tags: karma, dharma

I have heard these two terms many times. Karma (deeds) can be considered as either Kartavya or Dharma. But which kind of Karma is Kartavya or which one is Dharma.

For example: If a son does seva to their parents then it is called that he performed his Putra Dharma. And when some one does any help to unknown person then it is called Manavta Dharma.

Earlier I thought Kartavya is usually is like Duty. Means if we are working under someone to earn, i.e.  doing Job then all of our activities in job will be considered as Kartavya. But when I heard term like **Sevak Dharma** then I got confused again. Sewak is also performs activities like one perform in job. And if Sewak activities towards his/her swami will be considered as Sewak Dharma then what kind of Activities is Kartavya?

Which kind activities should be called as Kartavya and which one should be called as Dharma. How to differentiate between these two?

Comment: According to Gita, *Kartavya* is a subset of *Dharma* & *Dharma* is synonymous to "*SAtvika* way of life". Hence there is apparent **no differentiation** between them.

Comment: @iammilind Ok, but is there any activity that can be called only Kartavya, not Dharma (not Dharma doesn't mean adharma here) ?

Comment: "*Kartavya*" means "do-able" (or responsibility). Whatever is "do-able" -- is defined according to *Dharma*. Hence there may not be any activity, which is only *Kartavya*, but not *Dharma*.

Comment: Your points seems valid. You should post your views as answer in detail.