# Can I say my Dharma is Karma?

Tags: karma, dharma

I do not subscribe to any religion.
I am confused about my Dharma.

Can I say my Dharma is Karma?

Comment: Related: [Difference between Kartavya and Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20035/277)

Comment: Do you mean Swadharma instead of Dharma?

Comment: @TheDestroyer No.

Comment: @DheerajVerma Your question is unclear, what do you mean by "is Dharma my karma?" Explain what is Dharma here.

Comment: I am surprised. Don't you have a Dharma? If I ask you what is your Dharma what will be your answer ? I am talking about same Dharma.

Comment: bro karma is action prescribed by one's dharma and dharma is duty. so it is dutyfull action.

Comment: @Fiercelord can I say my duty is to do karma ?

Comment: Yes lord krishna himself said you have right to do karma not on its fruit —(read my answer here) https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23971/what-are-the-characteristics-of-a-human-being/23978#23978  even he can not change one's karmas originally. l do not believe caste,etc  vedas specially rigveda and samaveda say duties for people all people not for caste etc. :) so above given link has answer to your question.

Comment: That answer is unsatisfactory. Is every karma my Dharma ? Suppose I intend to steal then is it my Dharma to steal ?

Comment: @Dheeraj Verma karma is action good karma makes a man gain virtue while bad karmas make him down now dharma is apart from karma, action that upholds dharma is called is called good karma or dharmic karma and if bad then adharma above all is nishkama karma karma done without any desire and not taking intrests in its fruit and giving it in holy feet of god.